# app-release is not installed in real device Flutter

Tags: flutter, apk

[image]

I am releasing apk this way(shown on image)

I have release apk file from build/flutter/Build apk but is not installed in any real devices and its give me error **"App is not installed as package appears to be invalid"**. Can you please help me how to solve this error I am stuck in this problem. This app is run nicely in debug mode from run command.

I have tried this solution:

1. Uninstall old app and then tried to installed this app
2. Restart real device and then tried to install this app
3. Create new apk release file and tried.
4. Flutter clean and Flutter get done.
5. Tried to install more than 5 devices but same error in every real device.

Comment: Please show the full command line you are using to build the release, including the directory location, and explain how you are trying to install it on the device.

Comment: I am using Android studio, on the top menu there is option build, i am releasing Api this way. I am edited my question and add screenshot @GrahamD

Comment: Ah, I use VSCode not AS. Even so, I build release apks using the command line from my project folder eg. `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64`. That generates the apk in the folder `build\app\outputs\flutter-apk`. I then transfer that apk to my android device and install it.